# Discrepancy in reputation counts between user list and profile graph

Tags: support, reputation-leagues, reputation-graph

There seems to be some sort of discrepancy in reputation calculation. On [my profile page](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/13438/alex) it shows my total reputation as 41,819 and it shows a graph which goes back to February of this year, wherein the earliest point viewable on the graph shows my reputation as 33,264.

[image: Screenshot of profile page showing reputation graph]

If this is the case then I would have had to have earned no less than 8,555 reputation this year (41,819 - 33,264) and probably even more since the graph doesn't seem to be including January.

Yet on the [users tab when sorted by year](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=year) it shows that I have only earned 7,855 reputation this year:

[image: Screenshot of yearly reputation page]

Similarly, the [yearly league page](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/248/year/judaism) shows that I have earned 7,855 reputation this year:

[image: Screenshot of yearly reputation league page]

Unless I'm missing something these cannot both be mathematically correct. And I don't think it can simply be an issue of waiting for the next update or something like that, because the difference is a full 700 reputation (which at the rate I have been earning reputation is at least a few weeks).

So which location is displaying the wrong data? Or are they counting different things (e.g. including bounties, excluding lost reputation, etc.)?

Comment: It may take a while for the reputation differences to sync.